# Equivalent electrical circuit changing and power balance calculation

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, equivalent-circuit

I tried to change this circuit in three different ways, but the power balance is not the same. The least power balance that I got was ~50 W more and we need to find the balance between 0 and 5 W. Ignore the number 16 in the picture; it is the variant number. I would really appreciate the help.

U=100 V;
R1=7,6 Ω;
R2=6 Ω;
R3=8 Ω;
R4=12 Ω;
R5=10 Ω;
R6=7 Ω;
R7=7 Ω.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your coloured pencils or felt-tip pens or crayons and, superimpose a coloured line on the node that is to the left of R2. Then, in a different colour mark the node on the right of R2. Then, do you see that R2, R3 and R4 are all in parallel.

Redraw and simplify.

Does this help?

---

**EDIT** - The OP's struggling so here's what I aid above as a picture: -

[image]

Comment: I tried doing it this way but the power balance is too high around 50~60W.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean.

Comment: I simplified the circuit to R2-4 they are in parallel, then R5-7 are in the same line I simplified those too and lastly I simplified the circuit to R1567 and R234. After that I calculated resistors equivalent, then I divided U=100V from resistor equivalent. From that I found every resistors I (ampers) and then put I^2×R for power balance, and I still got over 50W.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What is the resistance you calculated?

Comment: R1567=5,77 (ohm) and R234=2,67 (ohm). R equivalent =8,44 (ohm). I equivalent = 5,24A

Comment: Are you saying that R1 + R5 + R6 + R7 = 5.77 ohm @DontKnow

Comment: Yes. Because our professor said that we sum R5+R6+R7 (they are on the same line) and then multiply by R1 on the top and on the bottom we write R1+R5-7. So the equation is (R1×R5-7)/(R1+R5-7). Only R5+R6+R7.

Comment: Well, calculating R1 + R5 + R6 + R7 doesn't help you find the Thevenin resistance but, as an aside, adding R1, R5, R5 and R7 doesn't get you 5.77 ohms. I've added a picture to help you @DontKnow

Comment: I've done exactly the same, but calculating R5+R6+R7 I get 24 ohms and writing the equation for R1567 - (R1×R567)/(R1+R567) = (7,6×24)/(7,6+24) = 5,77 ohms. I will try to recalculate, and redo all of it. Maybe it will help.

Comment: R1 is not in parallel with R567 @DontKnow R567 are in parallel with R234 and together, they are in series with R1. Just look at the circuit I drew you

Comment: Will recalculate everything. Thanks for the help, if I get the power balance too high will ask again. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm not sure why you refer to "power balance" <-- what is it meant to be or represent?

Comment: In our university we use power balance to determine if we calculated R and I correctly. Equation which is I1^2×R1+I2^2×R2+I3^2×R3 and so on, then we sum everything and make sure if U×I(equivalent) for example U=100V and I=15A the power balance can not exceed (5W) or be lower than (0W) so U×I=100×15=1500W

Comment: Figured it out, need to calculate (R5×R6)/(R5+R6) and then (R56×R7)/(R56+R7). Thank you for the help really appreciate it .

Comment: But the diagram shows that they are in series and not in parallel. Your calculation is for parallel resistances.